# More information for Not Enough Spatial Data problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

After many attempts to make a version of SpectatorView functional using UNet, I was able to successfully communicate between client / server using Azure Spatial Anchor to share anchor information. Many errors have occurred, including an unknown error, which appears to resolve the deletion of the MRTK 2.2.0 library. This has already been resolved, but now at random a problem occurs in the function **CloudManager.CreateAnchorAsync**, which says just like this: Not enough Neighborhood Spatial Data was available to complete the desired Create operation.

This problem does not happen directly, but randomly makes it impossible to find a pattern to try to think of a solution to this problem.

Remembering that the **CloudManager.SessionStatus.RecommendedForCreateProgress** variable is above 1 before calling the creation function.

Could you give me more information about this problem? What do I do to not do a project to solve it?